# Extract the key value from string of list of dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract the value corresponding to the "name" from the list of the dictionary which is a string.

```
[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, 
 {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, 
 {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
```

I tried the below approach, but getting the error, `string indices must be integers`. Can someone assist me with respect to this, please.

```
for data in "[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]":
    print(data['name'])
```

Comment: At first you define a list of objects and inside the for loop you are using the list as string. Define a variable for the list ob objects and use it for the loop and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

On the right track, but you need to loop through the list, not a string:

```
my_list = [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]

for thing in my_list:
  print(thing["name"])
```